# Access violation reading location error in multithread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy

Check this code for possible multithreading errors, please. Sometimes I got an error "Access violation reading location" at line `cv.notify_all();` (marked in code).

```
uint64_t GetFirstAdvertisingBLEAddr()
{
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;

    BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher advWatcher;
    uint64_t addr = 0;
    bool stopCalled = false;
    auto recvToken = advWatcher.Received([&addr, &m, &cv](BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs) {
        ShowAdvertisement(eventArgs);
        addr = eventArgs.BluetoothAddress();
        watcher.Stop();
        std::unique_lock l(m);
        cv.notify_all(); // <----- HERE ------------------------------------
    });
    auto stoppedToken = advWatcher.Stopped([&stopCalled, &m, &cv](BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs eventArgs) {
        std::unique_lock l(m);
        stopCalled = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    });

    {
        std::unique_lock l(m);
        advWatcher.Start();
        cv.wait(l, [&addr, &stopCalled, &advWatcher] { return addr != 0 && stopCalled && (advWatcher.Status() == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus::Aborted || advWatcher.Status() == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus::Stopped); });
    }

    // remove event handlers
    advWatcher.Received(recvToken);
    advWatcher.Stopped(stoppedToken);

    return addr;
}
```

If you need some more code:

```
int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();

    std::wcout << "Main thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    uint64_t addr = GetFirstAdvertisingBLEAddr();
    if (addr == 0) {
        std::wcout << L"Failed to find advertising BLE device." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::wcout << "Found BLE device: " << GetDeviceName(addr) << std::endl;

    BluetoothLEDevice dev = BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(addr).get();

    GattDeviceServicesResult result = dev.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode::Uncached).get();
.......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutex and condition variable both go out of scope when the function `GetFirstAdvertisingBLEAddr` returns. The captured variables in your lambdas are then dangling and reading those variables makes your program have undefined behavior.

One possible workaround is to make them `static`:

```
static std::mutex m;
static std::condition_variable cv;
```

Comment: That is, the solution would be to transfer

     std :: mutex m;
     std :: condition_variable cv;

into the main () function? Can you write how to correct this code correctly?

Comment: @xikov You can test to just make them `static` like I showed. If that helps you can think about if you'd like to move them.

Comment: I got an errors: a variable with static storage duration cannot be captured in a lambda Here: auto recvToken = advWatcher.Received([&addr, &m, &cv]

Comment: @xikov You don't need to capture static variables. You can use them inside the lambdas anyway.

Comment: So, just use them without capturing?
auto recvToken = advWatcher.Received([&addr](BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs) {
  ShowAdvertisement(eventArgs);
  addr = eventArgs.BluetoothAddress();
  watcher.Stop();
  std::unique_lock l(m);
  cv.notify_all();
 });

Comment: "_So, just use them without capturing_" - Yes, exactly! You're welcome! Glad it worked.